# Каким образом совмещать Exceptions и Psr\Log?

Tags: php, ооп, исключения, логирование

Начал изучать логирования psr/log, поставить одну из реализаций `monolog`.
Насколько я понял, нам можно в зависимости от критичности (levels) лога, можно выполнять разные действия. Выводить в файл логи, или оповещать по почте и т.д.

Ранее, когда еще не знал о psr/log, я в проектах использовал обычные Exceptions, далее отлавливал из, и в зависимости от того, какое исключение было, выполнял теже действия (добавлял что-то в лог и т.д.).

Хотел бы узнать, какие есть способы совместить эти два механизма?

1. Перед моментом, когда я выбрасываю очередное исключение добавлять в лог сообщение об ошибке с соответствующим уровнем ? 
   Требуется ли в этом случае, для класса исключения, передавать ему дублирующее сообщение об ошибке, или достаточно добавления в лог?
2. Работать как и раньше, выбрасывая исключения разных классов. Далее, при использовании методов классов, отлавливать ошибки, и в зависимости 
   от класса исключения добавлять в лог сообщения выброшенных исключений ?
3. Или другой способ ?

Comment: В монолог можно добавить перехватчик предупреждений и исключений php

Comment: А можно пример пожалуйста, как это использовать?  Или где можно почитать?
Т.е. мне не совсем понятен подход. Методы классов должны выбрасывать исключения, далее монологу добавлю процессор обработки ошибок php и сключений, и в этом процессоре мне нужно будет через switch case перебрать все типы исключений и производить нужные действия с логами?

Comment: `$logger->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor());` - полезная вещь. `$errHandler = new ErrorHandler($logger);
    $errHandler->registerErrorHandler();
    $errHandler->registerExceptionHandler();
    $errHandler->registerFatalHandler();` - подключение хэндлеров